# Query value between two other values in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have the following structure in Firebase:

```
{
  "images": {
    "first_image": {
      "url": "https://ima.ge/first_image",
      "uploader": "john",
      "start": "1465920841",
      "end": "1466920841"
    },
    "second_image": {
      "url": "https://ima.ge/second_image",
      "uploader": "louis",
      "start": "1465920987",
      "end": "1476920987"
    },
    "third_image": {
      "url": "https://ima.ge/third_image",
      "uploader": "peter",
      "start": "1465920990",
      "end": "1484920990"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to query for example all the images where the current timestamp is between "start" and "end"? So if the current timestamp (which is milliseconds since the Unix epoch) is `1475920987`, it would return `second_image` and `third_image` but not `first_image` because the timestamp is not in the Range of start and end.

I'm afraid this is not possible because in other stackoverflow questions users pointed out that multiple queries are not possible. So if I want to do a voting system where the user can decide when others are allowed to vote, is it possible to show users only votable images? Even if multiple queries are not allowed?

I am using the iOS and Android Firebase SDKs but a language specific answer is not necessary.

Comment: There was a similar question a couple of months ago, but I can't find it right now. I don't think we found a solution there. The problem is that Firebase queries can only filter by a single property, so you'd need to find a way to combine the two values into a single property in a way that allows the filtering you're looking for. As said: I couldn't think of one back then, but maybe someone else comes up with a solution this time.

Comment: Might be not optimal but, you can try using nested queries to filter. For example retrieve all by end and then filter it with second query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `queryStarting(atValue:)` and `queryEnding(atValue:)` in a single query.

So you need something like:

```
let query = Database.database().reference().child("images")
    .queryStarting(atValue:<startTimestamp>)
    .queryEnding(atValue:<endTimestamp>)
```